# C: fgets for read file line by line -> to less memory provided?

Tags: c

I try to read a file line by line in C (but for some reasons, I want the lines to be concatenated into one string at the end!).

```
int max_line_length, finish_length, current_length;
max_line_length = finish_length = 50000;
current_length = 0;
line = malloc(sizeof(char) * max_line_length);
finished_line = malloc(sizeof(char) * finish_length);

while (fgets(line, max_line_length, file) != NULL) {

  if (line[strlen(line)-1] == '\n') {
    int len = strlen(line);
    char new_part[len];
    strncpy(new_part, line, len - 1);
    new_part[len - 1] = '\0';

    if ((current_length + (len - 1)) > finish_length) {
      while ((current_length + (len - 1)) > finish_length) finish_length*=2;
      finish_line = realloc(sizeof(char)*finish_length);
    }
    current_length+= strlen(new_part);
    strncat(finish_line, new_part, strlen(new_part));
    line[0] = '\0';
  } else {
    max_line_length *= 2;
    line = realloc(sizeof(char) * max_line_length);
  }
}
```

So I check if a newline was read, if not, it should mean there isn't enough memory in line, so I reallocate it, and then it will be read again, right?

I don't see what do i miss here, but valgrind is complaining following:

```
4,096 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 111 of 114  
at 0x47F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)  
==901==    by 0x180915: fgets (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
```

at the line where i call fgets!

But I am freeing both, the line and finished_line at the end of the method. Does someone see what do I miss here ???

Comment: did you run your code? i have noticed some syntax error already. please show us the code you are running.

Comment: yes sorry I did some mistakes while typing it, but it should be corrected now. Not nonsense Igore, just being to sloppy ;)

Comment: Yes, sorry guys, I've just incorporated 1000 mistakes while rewriting the code here. I think I corrected all of the mistakes. Sorry.. But still I don't see my valgrind leak :P

Comment: you should do: `len = strlen(len)` the `new_part[len-1] = '\0'` part.

Comment: `strncat(finish_length, new_part, strlen(new_part));` finish_length is an int; the first argument for str[n]ca() should be a pointer to char. at least..

Comment: Your algorithm implementation looks pretty weird... Could you please post a correct code which could be easily test be everyone?

Comment: @joop, oh yes, you are right! I switched the line and the length of

Comment: what about reallocs call? it is not valid with only one argument.

Comment: A decent compiler (with the correct warning level) should **at least** issue a warning for the wrong argument type.

Comment: it doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: How could this realloc call ever compile with one argument?

Answer (score 0):

see realloc's definition:

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

in your case, you don't provide any `ptr` argument in your call to realloc. For me, this doesn't even compile:

> error: too few arguments to function ‘realloc’

Realloc returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory. You should pass in the old pointer to realloc and make it return to the new one, like:

```
char* new_finished_line = NULL;
new_finished_line = realloc(finished_line, sizeof(char)*finish_length);
/* if realloc was successful, it already freed finished_line pointer
 * and it returned to new_finished_line */
if (new_finished_line != NULL) {
    finished_line = new_finished_line;
}
/* if new_finished_line is NULL, then finished line is still allocated */
else {
    free(finished_line);
    printf("realloc error\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

However, after some syntax fixes, your version on my machine did not made that memory leaks. Maybe think of redesigning your algorithm? You can try with the code below, where file is read char by char and if newline character was read, then space is written to buffer. There are many different ways of achieving that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* read_my_file(char* name) {
    char* store;
    char* new_store = NULL;
    int SIZE = 10;
    int x;
    int i = 0;
    store = malloc(SIZE);
    FILE* fp = fopen(name, "r");
    while (( x = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF) {
        if (x == '\n') {
            store[i] = ' ';
        }
        else {
            store[i] = x;
        }
        if (i > SIZE - 2) {
            SIZE *= 2;
            new_store = realloc(store, SIZE);
            if (new_store != NULL) {
                store = new_store;
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "realloc error");
                free(store);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    store[i] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);
    return store;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* container = read_my_file("YOUR_FILE_TO_READ.txt");
    printf("%s\n",container);
    free(container);
    return 0;
}
```

My algorithm might not be the greatest one, I just want to show that there are many ways of doing that.

Comment: if `realloc()` succeeds you must not call `free(finished_line)` afterwarde

Comment: Yes bu this doesn't solve the valgrind problem of fgets and freeing memory :S??? I am sorry I posted code with to many errors, but I am still struggling with the beginning problem I had :(